# Docker Image which uses another image for running test cases

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a BDD framework in Java which I am planning to dockerize. I am able to build and run that image as a whole. But what I want is:

To build 2 images, Image-1: Entire project (without feature files) & Image-2: Feature files.

Reason to do this is: My feature file will change often. I don't want to create my image again every time to install JDK and maven when there is only a change in the feature file.

What I expect is - Image-1 runs always as a container in background and when there is a change in feature files, I build Image-2 and start it as a container. This should trigger test by using already running container which has an entire dependency.

Comment: Let's see if I got this right, you have one image which is your application, and when feature files changes, this image have to adapt to it by re-running some command targeting feature files?

Comment: yes , second image which should be of feature files, will have entrypoint mention to run all the tests

Comment: So, it would be better to create a volume instead of a second image, don't you think? So, your first container would have a volume to your host and WHEN feature files were updated you just run a .sh on your container, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reason to do this is: My feature file will change often. I don't want to create my image again every time to install JDK and maven when there is only a change in the feature file.

If you just want to meet above requirement, what you is just `image inherit` like next:

**base/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# install JDK/MAVEN here
RUN xxx
```

**Build a base image now:**

```
$ docker build -t mybase:1 .
```

Then, for your application, use this base image:

**app/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mybase:1

# add new feature files here
ADD ... ...
```

Everytime, your feature file change, you could rebuild your app Dockerfile and run a container base on this new built out image. But, As the `JDK/MAVEN` is in another base image (`mybase:1`) which was already built there, so they won't be built again.

Comment: so even if i mention FROM mybase:1 in my second DockerFile, it will not built it again right?

Comment: This approach worked like a charm. Thanks to @atline